# Read three words exactly into one char array

Tags: c

I have a limited amount of variables to use so I would like to solve the following problem only using one variable. Is it possible?

```
  char str[100];
  // Type three words:
  printf("Type three words: ");
  scanf("%s %s %s",str,str,str);
  printf("You typed in the following words: \"%s\", \"%s\" and \"%s\"\n",str,str,str);
```

The following input gives the following output:

```
Type three words: car cat cycle
You typed in the following words: "cycle", "cycle" and "cycle"
```

Which isn't strange since the last read word is stored into the beginning of the same char array. Is there any easy solution to this?

Comment: How many variables are you allowed to use?  Is this homework or is reduction in variables an attempt to solve an unstated underlying problem (e.g. stack overflow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning each word to the same address of buffer, so they are going to be overwritten first by car, then by cat and last by the cycle.

Try to use 2D array, one dimension is which word it contains, the other is how many characters will it hold, 21 for 20 characters and one zero termination.

```
char str[3][21];
// Type three words:
printf("Type three words: ");
scanf("%s %s %s",str[0],str[1],str[2]);
printf("You typed in the following words: \"%20s\", \"%20s\" and \"%20s\"\n",str[0],str[1],str[2]);
```

This code will not read a word longer than 20 lines thus preventing overflowing the buffer and memory access violation. The scanf format string %20s will limit the reading to 20 chars.

Comment: You could change the format specifiers to `%20s` to limit the maximum length of strings written.

Comment: A lot of good answers in this thread. I chose this one because it was the easiest one. Gave +1 to the others with feasible solutions.

Comment: BTW:  Although "%s %s %s" is easier to read, "%s%s%s" has the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop?

```
char buf[0x100];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    scanf("%s", buf);
    printf("%s ", buf);
}
```

Sidenote: but why not read the entire line at once, then parse it later using e. g. `strtok_r()`?

```
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
```

is the way to go...

Comment: +1  It's sad to see only 1 answer with a loop as iteration should be the first considered option.  Also, the `fgets()` solves I/O and buffer over-run concern in one shot.

Comment: BTW, OP had 100, you have 0x100 - your standard buffer size.

Comment: @chux Yes, it's round. Better for the stack anyway :)

Comment: I posted an answer, now deleted, for I realized the contrived OP question did say "only using one variable" and both our solutions used 2.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how long the words can be, you can do something like that:

```
scanf("%s %s %s",str,&str[30],&str[70]);
```

and show it by:

```
printf("You typed in the following words: \"%s\", \"%s\" and \"%s\"\n",str,str[30],str[70]);
```

but it is not really elegant and safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is a worst way but still :

Just using random sizes for input strings

```
char str[100];
  // Type three words:
  printf("Type three words: ");
  scanf("%s %s %s",str,str+22,str+33);
  printf("You typed in the following words: 
          \"%s\", \"%s\" and \"%s\"\n",str,str+22,str+33);
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you can only use a single variable.  Instead of making that one variable be a single string (array of char), make it be an array of strings (2D array of char).

Answer (score 0):

If the input names are guaranteed to have letters less than a certain number, like 9, you can use this:

```
printf("Type three words: ");
scanf("%s %s %s",str,str + 10,str + 20);
printf("You typed in the following words: \"%s\", \"%s\" and \"%s\"\n",str, str + 10, str + 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a 2-D array:

```
char str[3][30];

printf("Type three words: ");
scanf("%s %s %s", str[0], str[1], str[2]);

printf("You typed in the following words: \"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", str[0], str[1], str[2]);
```